# centos ./configure error: libevent not found despite it is installed via yum

Tags: gcc, openssl, telegram, autoconf, libevent

I have a really strange problem. I am trying to compile a source (telegram-cli) which has dependency on openssl, libevent and other libraries.

The system is centos 6.9 
and "Development Tools" and libevent-devel and openssl-devel are installed via yum. By the way, ./configure results in this output:

Using this repo ([Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg)):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git && cd tg
```

./configure :

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing clock_gettime... no
checking for library containing backtrace... no
checking for event_base_new in -levent... no
configure: error: no libevent found
```

gcc -v -N :

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)
```

I also added this to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ :

```
/usr/lib64
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib64
/usr/local/lib
/lib
/lib64
/usr/lib64/openssl/engines
/usr/lib64/libevent-1.4.so.2.1.3
/usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so
/usr/lib64/libevent.so
```

The strange point is all these configs are the same on another centos system and everything just works fine. :(

I guess the libraries exist on the system but gcc or linker could not find them. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Suggest: `# yum reinstall libevent libevent-devel` .... No issues here, CentOS 6.9, "tg Telegram messenger CLI" : `# yum install jansson-devel lua-devel readline-devel libconfig-devel libevent-devel`. ..... ..... tg/ : `$ ./configure && make` : No errors.

Comment: Thanks but does not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need `libevent-devel`

```
yum install libevent-devel
```